# C# LINQ query for SQL Server UNBOUNDED PRECEDING Window Function

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, ef-core-6.0

I have a SQL table having data as shown below and I need a C# LINQ query for SQL Server `UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`  window function.
Any help would be appreciated

Table Data

| Date | EarnedMHRS | DayVal | MHRS | Per |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/8/2022 | 766 | 0 | 76.61834136 | 0.005743504 |
| 3/9/2022 |  | 1 | 418.13577 | 0.03134451 |
| 3/10/2022 |  | 2 | 1405.189433 | 0.105336539 |
| 3/11/2022 |  | 3 | 2907.939774 | 0.21798649 |
| 3/12/2022 |  | 4 | 3705.688573 | 0.277787749 |
| 3/13/2022 |  | 5 | 2907.939774 | 0.21798649 |
| 3/14/2022 |  | 6 | 1405.189433 | 0.105336539 |
| 3/15/2022 |  | 7 | 418.13577 | 0.03134451 |
| 3/16/2022 |  | 8 | 76.61834136 | 0.005743504 |
| 3/17/2022 |  | 9 | 8.645321518 | 0.000648075 |

SQL query which need to Convert into LINQ.

```
SELECT [Date],
        SUM(EarnedMHRS) OVER(ORDER BY DayVal ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) As EarnedMHRS,
        Round(SUM(MHRS) OVER(ORDER BY DayVal ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW),0) AS MHRS, 
        per      
        FROM TblPanning;
```

I tried below LINQ query but no success.

```
decimal? runningTotal = 0;
            decimal? runningTotalMHRS = 0;
            var tmpOutput2 = tmpOutput1.Select(item =>
                 {
                     runningTotal += item.EarnedMHRS;
                     runningTotalMHRS += item.MHRS;
                     return new
                     {
                         item.Date,
                         MHRS = item.DayVal == totalDays ? totallMhrs : Math.Round(runningTotalMHRS ?? 0, 0),
                         item.per,
                         EarnedMHRS = runningTotal,
                     };
                 });
```

**Output Required using LINQ**

| Date | EarnedMHRS | MHRS | per |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-08 | 766.00 | 77 | 0.00574350382867894 |
| 2022-03-09 | 766.00 | 495 | 0.0313445103804797 |
| 2022-03-10 | 766.00 | 1900 | 0.105336538836155 |
| 2022-03-11 | 766.00 | 4808 | 0.217986488988673 |
| 2022-03-12 | 766.00 | 8514 | 0.277787748142283 |
| 2022-03-13 | 766.00 | 11422 | 0.217986488988673 |
| 2022-03-14 | 766.00 | 12827 | 0.105336538836155 |
| 2022-03-15 | 766.00 | 13245 | 0.0313445103804797 |
| 2022-03-16 | 766.00 | 13321 | 0.00574350382867894 |
| 2022-03-17 | 766.00 | 13340 | 0.000648075073801102 |

Please help me out.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What does this query do? Are there any errors? What results do you expect?

Comment: @TanveerBadar I have added the desired output what I need

Comment: You can't write such queries in LINQ nor should you try to. ORMs like EF are trying to give the illusion of working with in-memory objects instead of tables. This breaks down badly with reporting queries like this, where there are no objects to begin with. You can use an ORM to map the results to objects though.

Comment: You can use eg Dapper or FromSqlRaw to execute the raw queries map the results directly to reporting objects. Or you can create a view with this query and map it as if it was a table.

Comment: The `runningTotal += item.EarnedMHRS;` clause won't work and isn't even what you asked for. Assuming it could be translated to SQL (it can't) it would require a `WHILE` loop to update T-SQL variables. The performance would be significantly worse than `SUM() OVER()`. The other alternative is to load the values in memory and *then* calculate the running total with `GroupBy` and `Aggregate`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I can't use SQL query or Dapper, as I need to convert SQL query to LINQ, many SQL transformations have already been done prior to this step, so I need help to convert this part.

Comment: You can't. There's no if or but about this. You aren't even using LINQ here. LINQ doesn't have any database-specific functions, those are provided by EF/EF Core. And neither of these has implemented windowing functions like `SUM OVER()`. The correct, easy, fast and scalable solution is to map to views, UDFs or raw queries. Both EF and EF Core allow you to map to SQL queries, so there's really no reason to use C# to calculate the running total.

Comment: The hard and *slow* solution is to calculate the running total on the client. You'll have to load all rows on the client and then either loop over them to update the running total field based on the previous value, or use `Aggregate` to get the current and previous row and emit a new one with the updated values. The loop is as fast if not faster and easier to write

Comment: BTW which ORM are you using? EF? EF Core? What version?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i am using EF core 6.0

Comment: You can use EF Core Extension, which can build such query. If you interested, I will create answer.